# Converting a text file to ascii in PYTHON code then ascii character

Tags: converters

I have tried many ways but they all seem to only either convert one character or nothing at all
Please help any suggestions appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Could you give an example?

Comment: show your efforts. Post some code please.

Comment: it is for a gcse controlled assesment and i have been asked to generate an eight digit randomly generated key and offset factor to then convert the text file to ascii